# Is there any way to call the share menu in a termux script?

Tags: termux, share-menu

I made a bash script for termux and at the end of it i want to  call the share menu to send a file made by my script by whatsapp for example

I really don't have any idea about how to do this.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: See [termux-share](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-share) and [termux-open](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data).